# Possible speed up to delete via temp table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, temp-tables, sql-delete

I am running a delete which removes all of the duplicates within a table. A duplicate is defined as a row where the tag_id, user_id, and is_self are all the same. My technique here is pretty standard, to preform this delete, since the tags_users table itself needs to be referenced to know if a duplicate exists a temp table is created so that a delete can be preformed from the same table that is being referenced. The problem is that this table is about a million rows so this query takes about an hour to run. I know this is related to the slow speed of defining this temp table and then referencing it as it is un-indexed.

```
DELETE FROM tags_users WHERE id IN ( 
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT A.id FROM tags_users as A, tags_users as B WHERE A.id > B.id AND A.user_id = B.user_id AND A.tag_id = B.tag_id AND A.is_self = B.is_self GROUP BY A.id 
    ) temp_dup_delete
);
```

I have reviewed the explain from this query listed here (Please note I'm on mysql 5.5 so I'm using EXPLAIN SELECT 1 to simulate EXPLAIN DELETE). I think the best possible solution to this is to define an index on the temp table, but I cannot figure out how to do this yet. The crux of my question here is: is there a way to improve the speed of this query considering the way it defines a temp table. Thank you to anyone that can help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach.  Use an aggregation query to find the minimum id for each set of key values -- this seems to be the row you want to keep.

Then, use `left outer join` to match to this table and delete all the rows in the original data that do not match.

```
delete tu
    from tags_users tu left outer join
         (select tag_id, user_id, is_self, min(id) as minid
          from tags_users
          group by tag_id, user_id, is_self
         ) tui
         on tui.id = tu.id
     where tui.id is null;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm a bit stumped right now as to why I cannot make it work. I have the following query  `SELECT *
 FROM tags_users tag_dups LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
   SELECT tag_id, user_id, is_self, min(id) as min_id
   FROM tags_users
   GROUP BY tag_id, user_id, is_self
  ) as dup_outer_join
  ON dup_outer_join.min_id = tag_dups.id
 WHERE dup_outer_join.min_id IS NULL;`

But its throwing this error: 
`#1054 - Unknown column 'tags_users.tag_id' in 'order clause'`

This seems odd since there is no order clause declared for this query, would you have any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: @IamJohnGalt . . . Perhaps you are running more than one query when you get the error.  MySQL should not be producing an `order by` error when there is no `order by` clause.